# accelerometer and gyroscope fusion using extended kalman filter

Tags: imu, gyroscope, accelerometer, sensor-fusion, noise

I'm working on my graduation project which is characterizing human body posture. I'm using IMU so I get measurements from the accelerometer and gyroscope and I'm wealing to fuse these two filters so I can get Roll and pitch using extended Kalman filter, I'm confused if I should use Euler angle or Quaternions with the EKF, IF so what are the steps to get roll ant pitch. using EKF

Answer (score 2):

You should be using quaternions for fusion for good behaviour. Addition and multiplication for quaternions will be swapped out by rotation composition operations for quaternions and your orientation dynamics will need to be linearised.

But you really shouldn't implement this from scratch if you can avoid it, you should be able to find plenty of EKF implementations that work with quaternions or other $SO(3)$ representations and reuse them.

Comment: I'm not finding many resources on this subject, and the ones found are not really well explained so   have the mathematical model for the extended Kalman filter ( that includes  the prediction step and correction )  but I don't understand  how to implement Quaternions or  euler angle with EKF